# Access to text entry speed data?

Tags: data-request

Anyone know where I could get access to text entry speed data?

the data could be something like this

```
f d 899
a d 920
```

The first two characters indicate the typed key and the last-typed key, respectively. The first line says typing `a` when last typed key is `f` takes 899 millisecond. I suspect depends on the last-typed key, typing the same key will have different speed in general.

And of course it should be an average value of a certain population.

Comment: Not to be a downer, but... I really don't think there's a dataset out there like this. My suggestion would be to write an app that does this (effectively a keylogger that aggregates stats). Out of curiosity, what's the need?

Comment: @Skram hi, yeah I figure it would be pretty rare. Just for research interest, haven't figured all out yet though.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any dataset like this one. But if you Google ["typing speed test data"](https://www.google.gr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=typing%20speed%20test%20data), you will see many websites that does exactly this. And most of them have a contact page. You shall contact with them (maybe all of them) and ask if they are willing to share their data.